# IOS Gamekit GKInvalidArgumentException Error

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit, connectivity

Hi I am using gamekit to connect two IOS device for transferring data between them, below is the code iam using here

```
.h 

@property (nonatomic,strong)GKSession *sessionObj;
...

.m

...
GKPeerPickerController *connectionPicker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
connectionPicker.delegate = self;

//NOTE - GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby is for Bluetooth connection, you can do the same thing over Wi-Fi with different type of connection
connectionPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
[connectionPicker show];

sessionObj = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"com.myapp.connect" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
sessionObj.delegate = self;
```

so when i run the app it goes to GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate

```
-(GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type{
 return sessionObj;
```

}
and once this it return from this delegate method it throw an error which say's

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GKInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A vaild GKSession object with a GKSessionModePeer mode must be supplied, or to create a default GKSession object return 'nil' in the implementation of -peerPickerController:sessionForConnectionType:. Supplied object was: (null description) with session mode: 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1335052 0x1155d0a 0x12dda78 0x12dd9e9 0x665e0 0x65798 0x64e9a 0x64e13 0x5d15cb 0x64cf7 0x63237 0xb781 0xb438 0x5099d6 0x50a8a6 0x519743 0x51a1f8 0x50daa9 0x1d67fa9 0x13091c5 0x126e022 0x126c90a 0x126bdb4 0x126bccb 0x50a2a7 0x50ba9b 0xc12d 0x75f5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Can you please let me know what's wrong in here.

Comment: Where do you set up your GKSession or GKSessionDelegate?  You're looking for a line like myGKSessionVariable = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];

Comment: Yes i have create the one and added just beneath connectionPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
[connectionPicker show];

Comment: and in delegate -(GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type; i am returning the same

Comment: i have just edited the question with updated code.

Comment: I Can able to figure it out, Since i was running the app on simulator so its getting terminated. when i run the same on real device its working fine.